# RTVS can't see my regular R, and is telling me to use Microsoft R Client

Tags: r, visual-studio, rtvs

I've installed R for Visual Studio (RTVS 1.0.30321.1407) on Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Professional 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3.

I already have regular R 3.4 on my machine, but the R Interactive window is telling me I need to install Microsoft R Client (which I don't want).  The message I get upon opening an R project is:

[image]

When I try to use the R Interactive window, I get this error message:

```
Interactive Window is disconnected from R session.
Open Workspaces window and either select local R interpreter or try connecting to a remote machine.
```

How do I tell RTVS to use the latest version of R (which is already on my machine)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new "workspaces" pane in RTVS (<s>I think you can open it under Windows or Layout menu</s> under menu **R Tools --> Windows --> Workspaces**) that lets you connect to R installs. **Add** an R install but specify the path to the local R install and it will work fine. You can also use it to connect to [Remote R installs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/rtvs/workspaces-remote-setup).

[image]

Comment: That's what I thought at first, and it certainly works on my machine which has R installed in `C:\Program Files\R`.  But on a separate machine, I have R installed on `\\CIFILEPRD01\Home\lebelinoz\R` (basically in my `Documents` folder) and the process of connecting to local R fails (by "fails", I mean it just hangs indefinitely).

Comment: @lebelinoz, looking at the `\\\` in your path is that a remote workspace? If so check out the link I just added about Remote workspaces. Unfortunately I've never used that feature.

Comment: Thanks.  What I might do instead is try to install R properly on that one machine.